# How to create array with static text

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

[image]

I want to make a table like this:

[image]

tried these codes but no luck:

```
={A2:A,D2:D, "ok"}
={A2:A,D2:D,ARRAYFORMULA("ok")}
```

what is the correct syntax?

Comment: That looks more like a couple of VLOOKUPs to me.. Arrayformula does this kind of thing.. https://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/array-formula-intro/ - like multiply range 'a' by range 'b' to create range 'c' for equal sized ranges..

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:D, "select A,D,'ok' where A is not null label 'ok'''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=FILTER({A2:A, SPLIT(D2:D&"♥ok", "♥")}, A2:A<>"")
```

[image: 0]